# How to export different functions with express

Tags: node.js, google-cloud-functions

I use this code for a repository hosted in a Google Cloud Repository.

I use this code for some functions of Google Cloud Functions.

I want use the same repository for different Functions.
I want that is possible this:

**Function 1 (account)**:

- account/users
- account/users/:userId

**Function 2 (info)**:

- info/comments
- info/comments/:commentId

This is my code:

```
const express = require('express');
const cors = require('cors');
const account = express();
const info = express();

account.use(cors({
    origin: '*'
}));
info.use(cors({
    origin: '*'
}));

const PORT = 5555;

const PORT2 = 5556;

const USERS = [
    {
        id: 1,
        firstName: 'John',
        lastName: 'Smith'
    },
    {
        id: 2,
        firstName: 'Jane',
        lastName: 'Williams'
    }
];

const COMMENTS = [
    {
        id: 1,
        firstName: 'John',
        lastName: 'Smith'
    },
    {
        id: 2,
        firstName: 'Jane',
        lastName: 'Williams'
    }
];

account.listen(PORT, () => {
    console.log(`Server running on port ${PORT}`);
});

account.get('/users', (req, res, next) => {
    res.json(USERS);
});

account.get('/users/:userId', (req, res, next) => {
    res.json(USERS.find(user => user.id === parseInt(req.params.userId)));
});

info.listen(PORT2, () => {
    console.log(`Server running on port ${PORT}`);
});

info.get('/comments', (req, res, next) => {
    res.json(COMMENTS);
});

info.get('/comments/:commentId', (req, res, next) => {
    res.json(COMMENTS.find(comment => comment.id === parseInt(req.params.commentId)));
});

module.exports = {
    account,
    info
};
```

Whit this i can deploy different functions **account** and **info** with same repo.
But i don't want to instantiate two express object i think is a bad practice.

I need to export two functions for different Google Cloud Functions.
How i can achieve this?

Comment: Didn't get your point.

Comment: @Sameer What is your doubt? I need to export two different functions that can receive different API request, but with the same express object. Is possible export different routes?

Comment: Why not use router.

Comment: Can you explain me how, and if is possible to export a specific route and if a route can have different API.

Comment: Do you strictly need to open two server at 5555 and 5556 port? Will it be a problem if you only open **ONE** port for your appliation?

Comment: @jese_moriarty no is good for me is there is only one port. I need to export two module for different Google Function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its better to organize your code. Create app.js file contain below code. Use one port.

```
const express = require('express');
const cors = require('cors');
const app = express();
const users = require('./users');
const comments = require('./comments');

app.use(cors({
    origin: '*'
}));
app.use('/users', users);
app.use('/comments', comments);

const PORT = 5555;
app.listen(PORT, () => {
    console.log(`Server running on port ${PORT}`);
});

/// place this in users.js    

const express = require('express');
const account = express.router;

account.get('/', (req, res, next) => {
    res.json(USERS);
});

account.get('/:userId', (req, res, next) => {
    res.json(USERS.find(user => user.id === parseInt(req.params.userId)));
});

module.exports = account;

// place in comments.js
const express = require('express');
const info= express.router;

const COMMENTS = [
    {
        id: 1,
        firstName: 'John',
        lastName: 'Smith'
    },
    {
        id: 2,
        firstName: 'Jane',
        lastName: 'Williams'
    }
];

info.get('/', (req, res, next) => {
    res.json(COMMENTS);
});

info.get('/:commentId', (req, res, next) => {
    res.json(COMMENTS.find(comment => comment.id === parseInt(req.params.commentId)));
});

module.exports = info;
```

Comment: Many thanks for your time this is a great answer, but i need to export a module for Google to bind to a specific Function. I need on index.js to export two different module that i can associate to a specific function. If I export 
module.exports = {
    checkout,
    customer
} 
I receive an error. @sameer

Answer (score 0):

```
const express = require('express');
const cors = require('cors');
const app = express();


app.use(cors({
    origin: '*'
}));

const PORT = 5555;

const USERS = [
    {
        id: 1,
        firstName: 'John',
        lastName: 'Smith'
    },
    {
        id: 2,
        firstName: 'Jane',
        lastName: 'Williams'
    }
];

const COMMENTS = [
    {
        id: 1,
        firstName: 'John',
        lastName: 'Smith'
    },
    {
        id: 2,
        firstName: 'Jane',
        lastName: 'Williams'
    }
];



app.listen(PORT, () => {
    console.log(`Server running on port ${PORT}`);
});

app.get('/users', (req, res, next) => {
    res.json(USERS);
});

app.get('/users/:userId', (req, res, next) => {
    res.json(USERS.find(user => user.id === parseInt(req.params.userId)));
});


app.get('/comments', (req, res, next) => {
    res.json(COMMENTS);
});

app.get('/comments/:commentId', (req, res, next) => {
    res.json(COMMENTS.find(comment => comment.id === parseInt(req.params.commentId)));
});

module.exports = app;
```

Comment: But i need to export two different module. If i export only app i cannot create two Google Function. I need something like module.exports = {one, two}; . When one and two are express functions.